# I want to copy update files from an already updated machine to a machine with super slow internt. Can I do this and how?

Tags: updates

I have a machine that I have updated online with a faster internet connection. I am now in a location where the connection speed is horrible. Can I move the files from the updated machine to the not updated one? Sorry I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a piece of software which is intended for these situations. It is called [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx)

It permits you to download packages on a computer for installation on another.